# Stack every n-th column of data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, while-loop, rbind

I have a large excel sheet which I need to import into R. My issue is that the sheet contains many small tables which are separated by empty rows and columns. The table titles are also separated from the table itself by an empty row.

You can look at the excel output [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1815dmxyZxuSAmVsUocRooqrahntdVcY9/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101759005525130926561&rtpof=true&sd=true).
I would like to have a list of all data.frames on the sheet which are correctly named.

Edit: I have removed all empty rows and columns so now I am left with many columns where every fourth column, a new table begins.

```
results[1:8,1:10]
                                      c01                    c02                 c03                 c04                                     c05                  c06
1 response of AUT_E3CI to AUT_E3CI shocks                   <NA>                <NA>                <NA> response of AUT_E3CI to AUT_HICP shocks                 <NA>
2                                    <NA>            lower bound              median         upper bound                                    <NA>          lower bound
3                                     1.0                    1.0                 1.0                 1.0                                     1.0                  0.0
4                                     2.0 -0.0017003281610081986 0.06962694180009907 0.11535402387039681                                     2.0   0.0320783162263377
5                                     3.0   -0.01232670095304385 0.08512933823225599 0.22707701169618283                                     3.0 0.023014339564983166
6                                     4.0   -0.09369238952198494  0.0904834548010296 0.47546694990618454                                     4.0 -0.05144787826814039
7                                     5.0    -0.2301596729710727 0.03155987208641617  0.6502910254692547                                     5.0 -0.11117305002762731
8                                     6.0    -0.4024596506843293 0.10607314703381547  1.3257182896467359                                     6.0 -0.47648920768332415
```

Now I would like to rbind all columns into a single data.frame of four columns, that is stack all tables on top of each other in one long table of four columns. I have tried it with a while-loop which rbinds the whole data.frame onto itself in sets of four columns.

```
while (ncol(results)>4) {
  results <- rbind(results[,1:ncol(results)/2], 
                   results[,(ncol(results)/2)+1:ncol(results)])
   
}
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(results, , (ncol(results)/2) + 1:ncol(results)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Does anyone know how to fix the loop or knows an alternative approach?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're starting with something similar to this:

```r
dat <- structure(list(V1 = 11:13, V2 = 21:23, V3 = 31:33, V4 = 41:43, V5 = 51:53, V6 = 61:63, V7 = 71:73, V8 = 81:83, V9 = 91:93), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
dat
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
# 1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91
# 2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92
# 3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93
```

where you want to take every set of (say) 3 columns and stack them. Try this:

```r
datspl <- split.default(dat, (seq_along(dat) - 1) %/% 3)
datspl <- lapply(datspl, `colnames<-`, colnames(datspl[[1]]))
newdat <- do.call(rbind, datspl)
newdat
#     V1 V2 V3
# 0.1 11 21 31
# 0.2 12 22 32
# 0.3 13 23 33
# 1.1 41 51 61
# 1.2 42 52 62
# 1.3 43 53 63
# 2.1 71 81 91
# 2.2 72 82 92
# 2.3 73 83 93
```

This assumes that the names from the first four columns are appropriate for all other sets of 4 columns.

(Replace my `3` with `4` if you're doing every 4 columns, everything else should just work.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reshape` in R:

For example using the data provided by `r2evans` we could do:

```
n_cols <- 3
reshape(dat, matrix(names(dat),ncols), dir = 'long')

    time V1 V2 V3 id
1.1    1 11 21 31  1
2.1    1 12 22 32  2
3.1    1 13 23 33  3
1.2    2 41 51 61  1
2.2    2 42 52 62  2
3.2    2 43 53 63  3
1.3    3 71 81 91  1
2.3    3 72 82 92  2
3.3    3 73 83 93  3
```

Then get rid of the `id` and `time` columns If you do not need them.